# most efficient way to loop through log records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have a table that logs when a user logs in and out of a PC.  the table is designed like this:

LogTable:

```
[event_time]|[userID]|[CompName]|[event_type]|[Location]
```

an example of a person logging into a computer would be:

```
2014-08-18 10:11:17.000 | smith217 | library2123 | 1 | 13
```

most of the table is self explanatory.  the event type is whether the user logs in or logs out.  a '1' would be logging in, and a '0' would be logging out.

I'm looking for the most efficient way to loop through these records and find out which computers are available in a specific location.

I'm currently using this:

```
SELECT CompName, 
       event_type 
FROM   LogTable o
WHERE  Location = 13 
       AND EXISTS (SELECT * 
                   FROM   LogTable i 
                   GROUP  BY CompName 
                   HAVING Max(i.[event_time]) = o.[event_time] 
                          AND i.CompName = o.CompName) 
ORDER  BY CompName
```

This works by getting the most recent `event_time` and `CompName` that happened for each `computer` at a `location`, but runs very slowly as we get thousands of these logs a week.  I'd just like to know if there is a more efficient query for this that I'm not coming up with.

I'm running MSSQL

Comment: Do you have a table that contains every PC name to compare against?

Comment: `SELECT 1` might be more efficient than `SELECT *` because you don't actually care about the value, just if one is there or not. I doubt it would be a significant gain though

Comment: @JiggsJedi I could!  If that would help, it's something I could create.

Comment: It would be easier to devise a list of available PC's if you know what PC's you have... if you use the log as your basis, thats fine, but if a PC is never used, it would never show as available... no?

Comment: @JiggsJedi i'm not entirely sure what you mean, but yes, if a PC was never used, it wouldn't have any records. that will never be the case though as all these PC's are used frequently.  there will always be a record

Comment: @JonK wouldn't that always ONLY return the 1's though?  if the most recent event_time event was a 0, i wouldn't know that from that query, would i?

Comment: @JonK No, `SELECT 1` will not be more efficient than `SELECT *`. SQL Server doesn't care what you put there - even `SELECT 1/0` will work. It *knows* that an `EXISTS` subquery doesn't return any data...

Comment: @Edward That subquery doesn't return data, it only returns a true or false depending on whether rows were found or not.

Comment: Interesting, and good to know. Thanks @AaronBertrand - I have learnt something new today :)

Comment: @JonK Of course, that's not true when the query or subquery *returns* data. But for EXISTS / NOT EXISTS, it really doesn't matter. I prefer `SELECT 1` not for performance but just as an additional clue that the clause doesn't return anything...

Comment: @AaronBertrand but that subquery DOES edit what comes back.  I get a list of every log without it, and i only get a list of the most recent log events with it.  I get one event per PC with it, and hundreds per PC without it.  so it cant be JUST checking to see if they exist.

Comment: @AaronBertrand isn't that what the comparison does?  the i.[event_time] = o.[event_time]

Comment: *sigh* I'm saying you can't somehow look at the *output* of the subquery that is introduced using `EXISTS`. Essentially it only returns a boolean. But yes, if a row is returned by `IF EXISTS`, that means it matched the `WHERE` clause. Of course using `HAVING(MAX(datetime))` to match is risky, since two events *can* happen at the same time. But the answer below by @JiggsJedi addresses that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, assuming every PC name is in the log at least once.

In `LogCTE`, I'm adding a `row_number()` by `compname/Location` in descending order so '1' is always the last event... so if you select all the 1's you only have the last event be it, an in/out.

If you find this performs poorly, then I would look at the execution plan and see if there are any indexes you might need to help performance.

Ex:

```
/* create a table to test with*/
declare @log table (event_time datetime, userid varchar(15), compname varchar(15), eventtype int, location int)
/* add some fake data to test with */
insert into @log
select '2014-08-18 10:11:17.000','smith217','library2123',1,13 union
select '2014-08-18 10:12:17.000','smith217','library2123',0,13 union
select '2014-08-18 10:13:17.000','jones217','library2123',1,13 union
select '2014-08-18 10:14:17.000','smith217','library2124',1,13 union
select '2014-08-18 10:15:17.000','hemmingway217','library2125',1,13 union
select '2014-08-18 10:16:17.000','hemmingway217','library2125',0,13

/* CTE = computed table expression */
/* CTE's must be used immediately following creation, and are only good for ONE query */
;with LogCTE AS
(
    /* cte content, is * from @log our test table */
    /* adding a row_number(), in this case partitioned by compname/location in descending order */
    select *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY COMPNAME, LOCATION ORDER BY EVENT_TIME DESC) AS LastEvent
    from @log
)

/* cte looks like this if you did select * from logcte */
/*
event_time              userid          compname    eventtype   location    LastEvent
2014-08-18 10:13:17.000 jones217        library2123 1           13          1
2014-08-18 10:12:17.000 smith217        library2123 0           13          2
2014-08-18 10:11:17.000 smith217        library2123 1           13          3
2014-08-18 10:14:17.000 smith217        library2124 1           13          1
2014-08-18 10:16:17.000 hemmingway217   library2125 0           13          1
2014-08-18 10:15:17.000 hemmingway217   library2125 1           13          2
*/

/* we only want the last action per PC, so select lastevent=1 and add your other conditions */
select compname, eventtype
from LogCTE
where LastEvent=1
and location=13
```

Comment: thanks very much for the response.  it'll take me a second to digest everything as i'm not the best at SQL, but i promise i'll get back to you with this as i fully understand it.

Comment: Let me know if you have questions, in the mean time I'll update w/better comments for you.

Comment: got it!  you and t_m gave the similar answers when it comes down to it.  he's sorting by max ID while you're creating a last even record based on row number.  Since you answered first I'll give you the answer selection.  Really appreciate the help!  Thank ya, sir.

Answer (score 0):

@JiggsJedi .. Thanks for generating data.

@EdwardG.. If you already have a identity column and indexed, you can try the example below where it gets the last entry based on Location and CompName. Order by will give you an performance hit if you have lots of records.

```
    declare @log table (id int identity(1,1), event_time datetime, userid varchar(15), compname varchar(15), eventtype int, location int)

insert into @log
select '2014-08-18 10:11:17.000','smith217','library2123',1,13 union
select '2014-08-18 10:12:17.000','smith217','library2123',0,13 union
select '2014-08-18 10:13:17.000','jones217','library2123',1,13 union
select '2014-08-18 10:14:17.000','smith217','library2124',1,13 union
select '2014-08-18 10:15:17.000','hemmingway217','library2125',1,13 union
select '2014-08-18 10:16:17.000','hemmingway217','library2125',0,13



select compinfo.*
from @log compinfo
inner join
(
    select max(id) as id, Location, CompName
    from @log
    where Location = 13
    group by location, compname
) lastinfo
on compinfo.id = lastinfo.id
```

Comment: I don't like the `max(id)` approach because it is possible to have events recorded in a different order than chronological.

Comment: Really appreciate the help.  Since you and Jiggs had similar answers, but he answered first, I'm choosing his, but I really appreciate the response.